# How to reference an external function from inside a unit

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have two files. The first, `a.pas`, contains:

```
uses b;

function f(x: integer): integer;
begin
    f := x+1;
end;

begin
    writeln(g(10));
end.
```

The file `b.pas` contains:

```
unit b;

interface
function g(x: integer): integer;

implementation
function g(x: integer): integer;
begin
    g := f(x)*2;
end;

end.
```

Is it possible to somehow reference the function `f` defined in `a.pas`? I thought about using the `forward` keyword like this: (`b.pas`)

```
unit b;

interface
function g(x: integer): integer;

implementation
function f(x: integer): integer; forward;
function g(x: integer): integer;
begin
    g := f(x)*2;
end;

end.
```

But it doesn't work. It gives a "Forward declaration not solved" error.

I also thought about using the `external` keyword but, in order to use the external `f` function, `b.pas` requires `a.pas` to be already compiled (but `a.pas` require `b.pas` as well).

The only way to do this seems to be moving `f` (interface and implementation) to a new `helper.pas` file, and modifying `b.pas` like this:

```
unit b;

interface
function g(x: integer): integer;

implementation
uses helper;
function g(x: integer): integer;
begin
    g := f(x)*2;
end;

end.
```

I would prefer not having a `helper.pas` file. But maybe it's just impossible?

Comment: Move 'uses b' to implementation in unit a. And use unit a in interface in unit b.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't understand. 'uses b' is currently on top of `a.pas`, where should I move it? You say "to implementation in unit a" but `a.pas` doesn't have an `implementation` section, am I wrong?

Comment: It has, see http://wiki.freepascal.org/Unit#Format

Comment: @SertacAkyuz what do you mean? `a.pas` is not a unit, or is it?

Comment: Look at your question, you say your b.pas begins with 'unit b;'. You very much have a unit there.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, `b.pas` is a unit, but `a.pas` is not... maybe I'm missing something... you were talking about "unit a", right?

Comment: I was, and I missed it isn't a unit. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

With the current source code layout it is not possible. If you do not want to make a.pas a unit (why?), you can rewrite function g to have a function parameter:

```
{$ifdef FPC}
  {$mode delphi}
{$endif}

type
  tintfunc = function(x: integer): integer;

function g(x: integer; f: tintfunc): integer;
begin
  g := 2*f(x);
end;

function f(x: integer): integer;
begin
  f := x+1;
end; 

begin
  writeln(g(3,f));
end.
```

There are other methods (including global function pointers), but function parameters are IMO the most clean/safe way to implement it.

Comment: I think there would be no problem for me in making `a.pas` a unit. I can't modify the function `g`. How do I do this? :)

Comment: But wait: if I make `a.pas` a unit, then I must create a third file (with the main program). My goal is to have only 2 files and not more.

Comment: I have given you the source code for the modified g. If you do not want to change the source, you cannot implement the feature.

Comment: I know :( apparenty it's a Pascal's limitation (in C/C++ it can be done with function prototypes)